# Speech procession looking for repeats in spoken words in a sentence

Tags: python, machine-learning, speech-recognition

I am using the Python Librosa library. Can someone point me to a way i could find out whether there is are repeated words in a spoken sentence? I was thinking of using an autocorrelation function to uncover the repeats.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking autocorrelation isn't working here. You should cut the sentence to word (by finding parts with low segnal during x ms). And then to check the similarity of them